# Create a PHP laravel Controller to load view

Tags: php, laravel

After some time working on **codeigniter**, we are starting a project on **Laravel**, but i get stuck at the beginning.

I cant understand, where i define the path to chose the controller i want for work:
define main controller path load -> *My_first_proyect.php*

Cant understand where i can load my views from my resources/*views.balde.php*:
controller My_first_poryect: 
    index -> Load view -> view.blade.php

Thanks and sorry if my question is basic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Laravel are you using? Since Laravel 5 you should define your routes and controllers in the file routes/web.php

**web.php**

`Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@show');`

**app\Http\Controllers\UserController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Show the profile for the given user.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return View
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
    }
}
```

Checkout https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers

Answer (score 1):

You'll load the view from within the corresponding controller method. For instance:

```
public function index()
{

    $employees = Employee::all();

    return view('employees.index')->with('employees', $employees);

}
```

Laravel will translate `employees.index` to `resources/views/employees/index.blade.php`.

Next you will modify the `routes/web.php` file. You can define routes in a number of different ways, however for most use cases you'll probably want to define your controllers as [resourceful](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#resource-controllers), and so the route definition would look like this:

```
Route::resource('employees', 'EmployeeController');
```

This means your `index` view would be accessible via an HTTP call to `/employees/`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hey ty so much!, it help me a lot, but where can add this line to add my function index? "routes/web.php" i think is for determine the main veiw to see or is there where i add my main controller? T_T hate to be new in laravel all this sound so basic to start with T_T i tyso much for helping

Comment: Hi @clausvargas I have modified the the response to answer your followup question.